# Is a media CDN bad for image SEO?

Tags: seo, cdn

I found a [blog post on Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/blog/7412852-10-must-know-image-optimization-tips) about image optimization with the following statement:

> By placing your images on a CDN, you are most likely removing the image from your domain and placing it on the domain of the CDN. So when someone links to your image, they are actually linking to the CDN domain.

Is this true? If so, how does it affect SEO?

Comment: One could easilly setup a cname of their own domain such as `cdn.exmaple.com` which points to the cdn. Then in the event they stop using the CDN they still have full control over the url that images were being loaded from.

Comment: See also: [What to do when changing or moving off of a CDN to redirect images?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123962/what-to-do-when-changing-or-moving-off-of-a-cdn-to-redirect-images)

Answer (score 5):

Using a CDN such as that provided by AWS, is a great way to deliver your images with optimum speed. If you use Google PageSpeed Insights they often recommend this type of tactic. This is great for load times and hence great for SEO.

If image indexation is important to you, you should also list images in a dedicated image sitemap. Also ensure your images have relevant optimised `alt` attributes and file names.

CDNs are good for SEO for a number of reasons, so yes, you should deploy content in this way.

Answer (score -2):

The work of CDN is to spread your content through the Internet quickly, affordable, and secure all over the world. This image is not bad for SEO.