# When you use a cdn to deliver images how does google index it?

Tags: seo, google, cdn

I have started using a CDN on my website, the image links are as follows:

```
"https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_lossy,ret_img/https://my-domain-name.example/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-1.png
```

In this case, how does Google index the image?
Does it index the images with the CDN link or it skips the CDN link and indexes the images as

```
https://my-domain-name.example/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-1.png
```

The image links in the meta is the original, while the image links in the content is the one with cdn.

So if someone searches my website on Google image search, the links to the image with be with CDN or without CDN?

Comment: The "Does it effect SEO" part of your question is answered here: [Is CDN bad for image SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124052/is-cdn-bad-for-image-seo)  I'm editing that out so that your question is more narrowly focused on the parts that aren't answered on this site already.

Comment: "The image links in the meta is the original," Which meta? Can you show exactly what you are doing?

Comment: There is image links in <meta property="og:image"